# DiscordJS - Returning a role as 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm creating a verification bot and I pulled these constants from a slash command.

```
const nv = interaction.options.getRole('nonverified');
const v = interaction.options.getRole('verified');
```

In the console that const returns me '<@&roleid>'. So, I replaced that like this:

```
const nvr = nv.toString().replace('<@&', '');
const vr = v.toString().replace('<@&','');

const nvs = nvr.toString().replace('>', '');
const vs = vr.toString().replace('>', '');
```

Now I get what I wanted, just the roleid. I connected those constants to the other file like this:

```
const { vs, nvs } = require("../../Commands/Moderation/createverify");
```

But now, in the second file, those constants return as 'undefined' so when I use them in
`interaction.guild.roles.cache.get(vs);` they don't work.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpE4v.jpg - Here are the images of the two files. In the first picture, you can see that there is a module.exports = {} but in the second file it returns 'undefined'.

Comment: Did you export the constants in the first file? You need to do something like `module.exports = { vs, nvs }`.

Comment: `getRole` returns a `Role` or an `APIRole` so you could just grab the `id`s of them like: `const nonVerified = interaction.options.getRole('nonverified').id` and `const verified = interaction.options.getRole('verified').id`. Also, as @Drarig29 mentioned, check if you've exported them in the first place.

Comment: The .id at the end works but I don't know what you mean by the export. The whole first command is under the module.exports { }. I tried to add another one at the end just for the v and nv but it doesn't work.

Comment: Oh, but are you getting these variables in a function? Or is your code at the top-level of the file? If you update `module.exports` after your file is `require`d, then you'll just import empty values (i.e. `undefined`).

Comment: Can you post the full content of the file where you use `module.exports`?

Comment: @Drarig29 I added a imgur link at the bottom of the question but I'll send you the pastebin of the first command from which I want to pull the constants from. https://pastebin.com/HgjfjTBZ

Comment: I connected the files through a database so I kinda fixed it. Thanks.